# How to select rows based on datetime

Tags: mysql, database

I have to select some rows where the date is today or higher and I can select only the registers where the time is ten minutes before the current time. My doubt is on how to do that with 'datetime' type. Down below is the query:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(timee.nome_time
        ORDER BY timee.nome_time
        SEPARATOR ' X ') AS nome_time,
    partida.id,
    DATE_FORMAT(partida.data_hora, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_hora,
    partida.tb_cotacao_id
FROM
    tb_partida AS partida,
    tb_time AS timee,
    tb_partida_time AS partidaTime
WHERE
    (partida.id = tb_partida_id
        && timee.id = tb_time_id)
        AND (partida.flag_ativo = 1
        AND partida.flag_cancelado <> 1
        AND partida.flag_finalizado <> 1)
        AND partida.tb_campeonato_id = 11
GROUP BY partida.id
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `date(partida.data_hora) >= date(now())` in your where clause?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(),<datetime_field>)` to get the time difference and convert it to seconds. For greater than 10 minutes it will be something like this

```
SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( now() , tb_time )) > 600 ...
```

**EDIT**

To get the rows that has time 10 minutes more than current time, just reverse the parameters inside the `TIMEDIFF`. ie.,

```
SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(tb_time, now() )) > 600 ...
```

Comment: If I do that on a row that has date December 30th and the time is, for instance, 1PM and the current datetime is December 29, 2PM the register wouldn't be selected, right?

Comment: The TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( now() , tb_time )) will convert the time difference to seconds current_time - tb_time. Your scenario will give -ve value which won't get selected.

Comment: Ok, so when I use TIME_TO_SEC it converts only the time in the datetime type, right? I think I got it. I'm gonna try it and post the result right away.

Comment: So, if do like you said I get an row that should not be selected because the time in the register is 1:30PM and the current is greater than that, as you can see here: [Img 1](https://s23.postimg.org/oczjm0oaj/Captura_de_tela_de_2016_12_29_14_35_10.png) . And when I don't use the conditional it returns me this: [Img 2](https://s23.postimg.org/or0vlm8e3/Captura_de_tela_de_2016_12_29_14_35_19.png)

Comment: Well, you only need the time part irrespective of the date, I will update the answer

Comment: Well, exactly what are you looking for ? the entry exactly 10 minutes before the current time or between 0 to 10 minutes or something else ?

Comment: Here's the thing, those registers are all football matches and I need the app to show all the matches from current date and greater but I can only show matches that didn't begin yet, so I can't load a match that is 10 minutes away from it's start, just by safety.